# How to add channels and categories with bot Discord

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Just wondering, what is the function for adding channels and categories? I searched everywhere and ".createChannel" just doesn't work. It tells me in console that the function doesn't exist. The docs I am using are https://discord.js.org/ and the solution just doesn't seem to be there. If anyone knows the answer to this it would be much appreciated. This is what I am trying to use:

```js
    message.guild.createChannel('channel-name', 'text', [{
        id: message.guild.id
    };
```

Comment: Do you have any code which you could provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With discord.js v.12 you need to use [`guild.channels.create()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create). With that you can pass a number of parameters including the type of channel `text`, `voice` or `category`.

With discord.js v.11 you need to use [`guild.createChannel()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Guild?scrollTo=createChannel).